# avoid angular ng-repeat displaying progress bar in all rows

Tags: angularjs, pug

I am trying to Upload documents based on a button click for a particular row. I am showing the progress of the file being uploaded. The issue I am facing is that since the button is being displayed using ng-repeat, all rows are now showing the progress. Is there any way I can make only the row where I click on the button display the progress?

```
 tr(ng-repeat='row in displayedCollection')
                        td {{ row.branchName}}
                        td {{ row.email}}
                        td {{ row.belongsTo.companyName }}
                        td
                            button.btn.btn-primary(ngf-select ngf-change="uploadDocuments($files,row._id)" ngf-accept="'image/*,.pdf,.doc,.docx'",multiple) Upload Documents
                                div(ng-show='progressVisible')
                                    .percent {{percentage}}%
                                    .progress-bar
                                        .uploaded(ng-style="{'width': percentage+'%'}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it happens because `progressVisible` is a common variable for all of them, what you need is a specific variable for just the single iteration

#### i.e.

```
ng-show="row.progressVisible"
```

#### or

```
ng-show="progressVisible[$index]"
```

and set the values accordingly in the function that uploads